# create unix alias for "ssh username@", and I would like to use it for any ipaddress.

Tags: unicode

create unix alias for "ssh username@", and I would like to use it for any ip address.

for example, 
alias go="username@"
usecase:
$go 10.1.1.1 ; implement => ssh username@10.1.1.1

Currently if i do $go 10.1.1.1, it is taking extra white space between @ and ip address. how can i remove it?

Comment: you are aware you can configure a default outgoing user in `config` in `.ssh` ?

Comment: You might want to add an explanation for why you specifically want to use an alias instead of some other method. Specifically, you might want to explain why the `~/.ssh/config` file doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using a function instead of an alias:

```bsh
function go() {
    ssh "username@$1"
}
```

But are you sure that this is what you want? Have you considered using your `~/.ssh/config` file? To override the default user name and set it to `username` you could add the following stanza:

```
Host *
    User username
```